# After Update using ExecuteNonQuery runs, changes in database are not registered

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, ado.net

I am trying to create a CRUD application in which I made a movie selector. My only problem is that my "update" button is not updating data.

Button handler code is executing but not updating data, and also not updating the database.

Furthermore, it is showing a dialog box "(Movie Record Updated)"

```cs
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\Final Project\CineMagic\MovieDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

private void updateMovieBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(nameBox.Text.Trim().Length) > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            myConn.Open();

            SqlCommand myComnd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE ListTable SET Quality=@quality, Rating=@rating, Type=@type, Director=@director, ReleasedIn=@released WHERE Name=@name", myConn);
            myComnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            myComnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameBox.Text);
            myComnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quality", qualityBox.Text);
            myComnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rating", ratingBox.Text);
            myComnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", typeBox.Text);
            myComnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@director", directorBox.Text);
            myComnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@released", releasedBox.Text);
                
            myComnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConn.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Movie Record Updated.", "Updated Successfully", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            display_data();
            resetFormControls();
        }
        catch (Exception myExc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(myExc.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Select a record to update.", "Select...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: The title says `DataGridView` but the code is using `TextBoxes`. Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, including EXACTLY what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should be using a data adapter - specifically a `SqlDataAdapter`. You call `Fill` to populate a `DataTable` and bind that to the grid via a `BindingSource`, then call `Update` to save the changes. You can check my ADO.NET examples [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?544701-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases).

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: You should have a primary key to use for updating since if in this case if `Name` chances it's impossible to find your record . Also capture what `myComnd.ExecuteNonQuery();` returns for success for failure.

Comment: if this code runs but DB is not updated - you're executing it in one DB but checking for results in another,

Comment: Check the BUILD ACTION and also the COPY TO OUTPUT DIRECTORY of MovieDatabase.mdf properties.

Comment: Thanks all of you, my issue is resolved.